# React getting the ID of clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick

I have 5 clickable links, each with unique ID. I am trying to get the ID of the link that was clicked. I have tried two methods but neither work as I would like.

Inside render I have:

```
this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) =>
  <a href={"/#/template"} id={dynamicData.id} onClick={() => this.reply_click(this.id)}>{dynamicData.name}</a>
  <a href={"/#/addTeams"}><button type="button" class="btn-lisa">Edit</button></a>
```

Basic method that returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?:

```
reply_click(clicked_id) {
  console.log(clicked_id);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an arrow function will maintain the context of `this` from the outside, which won't be the `this` you want. You could try to use a regular function (`function () { }`) instead, but I'm not sure if `this` will be what you want or not there either.

You can, however, definitely use `e.target.id` to get what you want:

```
onClick={e => this.reply_click(e.target.id)}
```

That said, you should really avoid creating functions inside of things as it can create significant performance issues. It's much better to just create a function and pass it in:

```
// somewhere above
const handleClick = e => this.reply_click(e.target.id);

// attribute
onClick={handleClick}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<a href={"/#/template"} id={dynamicData.id} onClick={() => this.reply_click(dynamicData.id)}>{dynamicData.name}</a>
```

or another way

```
<a href={"/#/template"} id={dynamicData.id} onClick={this.reply_click}>{dynamicData.name}</a>



reply_click(event) {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('id'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.reply_click(this.id)
```

`this` is your component scope, which means every attribute you defined in your component can be accessed by `this`. Probably you did not define `id` in this component.

You probably wanna do

```
 this.reply_click(dynamicData.id)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` inside the arrow function is the same as the this outside it. The `onclick` is already aware of the correct `this`, so use it like this:

```
onClick={this.reply_click(this.id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. The code you have provided doesn't work because `this` is bound to the current React component, instead you could access `id` of the clicked element using `e.target.id`:

```
this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) => {
  <a href="/#/template" id={dynamicData.id} onClick={(e) => this.reply_click(e.target.id)}>{dynamicData.name}</a>
  <a href="/#/addTeams"><button type="button" class="btn-lisa">Edit</button></a>
})
```

Unrelated, but still I want to note that you don't have to use `<a href={"blah"}` instead you can use `<a href="blah"` because the last one uses a string contant.